# C# access variable from form 1 with form 2

Tags: c#, forms, stack-overflow

I want to access variables and such from form 1 to form 2, I have one main form and then open another with some indicators, a timer keep rolling in form 2 to check variables and lists in form 1 and light or darken the indicators.
But I get "Stack overflow exeption" se picture

This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Diagnostik formDiagnostics = new Diagnostik();
```

Button that opens form 2:

```
private void buttonDiagnostics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        formDiagnostics.Show();
    }
```

Form 2:

```
public partial class Diagnostik : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Timer:

```
private void updateGUI_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(form1.ListServo1Inputs[0]) == true) { indicatorS1Di1.BackColor = Color.Green; }
        else { indicatorS1Di1.BackColor = Color.Gray; }
```

[Error screen dump picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbY6w.png)

Comment: Take a look at your callstack. You'll see a chain of constructors switching between Diagnostik & Form1.

Comment: Your form1 is being declared "new" (and you never show it).  You aren't referencing the form you have on the screen.  Pass the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass form1 into the constructor for formDiagnostics:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Diagnostik formDiagnostics;

    public Form1()
    {
        formDiagnostics = new Diagnostik(this);
    }
```

In the Diagnostik contructor, store the Form1 argument into a field/property:

```
public partial class Diagnostik : Form
{
    private Form1 form1;

    public Diagnostik(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
    }
```

You can then access your private Diagnostik.form1 field:

```
private void updateGUI_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(form1.ListServo1Inputs[0]) == true) { indicatorS1Di1.BackColor = Color.Green; }
    else { indicatorS1Di1.BackColor = Color.Gray; }
```

Comment: Thanks.
`Diagnostik formDiagnostics = new Diagnostik(this);`
"this" gives an error "not avaliable..." 
I added this like you wrote:
`private Form1 form1;

        

        public Diagnostik(Form1 form1)
        {
            this.form1 = form1;
        } `
An when I write form1.blabla the ListServo1Inputs show up but when I run the form I get:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Husmaskin GUI.exe

Additional information: Object reference has not been specified to an instance of an object?

Comment: I have edited my answer to correct a mistake I made.

Comment: Ok thanks.
I actually changed to using tabs instead of forms as it avoided the problem and gave a cleaner look

Answer (score 1):

On the screenshot I see that you're creating your Form1 inside your Diagnostik form constructor. At the same time, you're creating Diagnostic form inside Form1 constructor. So probably you just got an endless loop here.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the problem.